# How to add up multiple intervals and check if they complete a known interval?

Tags: arithmetic

If my initial/known interval is `[0,20)` or length `19`

And the 3 intervals are: `[0,5)`, `[5,10)`, `[10,20)`

Using the standard interval addition formula:

`[a,b]+[c,d] = [a+c,b+d]` I get the result `[15,35)` [[1]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interval+%5B0%2C5%5D+%2B+interval+%5B5%2C10%5D+%2B+interval+%5B10%2C20%5D) not `[0,20)`

How do I multiply them to check if they add up to the known interval?

Also, there are cases where the 3 intervals don't add up: `[0,5)`, `[5,10)`, `[15,20)` - in this case, the complete puzzle is missing interval `[10,15)`, so how do I check for that?

Comment: $[0,19)$ has length $19-0=19,$ not $20$. Also it looks more like you should be taking unions, not adding.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you mean intervals of integers, e.g., $[0,5)=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ (`range` in Python). To check whether given intervals $[a_i,b_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$, form a partition of $[A,B)$, you can do the following:

1. Sort the intervals in order of increasing $a_i$.
2. Check that $a_1=A$, $b_1=a_2$, $b_2=a_3$, ...,  $b_n=B$. If all of these hold, you have a partition. Otherwise not.

Comment: If you just want the union to be $[A, B)$ (rather than having a partition), you only need $b_i \leq a_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, \dots, n-1$.